# how would i upgrade this code to work with jquery 1.6.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

how would i upgrade this code to work with jquery 1.6.2 as it only seems to work if i use  Version 1.2.6.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var container = $('div.sliderGallery');
        var ul = $('ul', container);

        var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();

        $('.slider', container).slider({
            min: 0,
            max: itemsWidth,
            handle: '.handle',
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui.value);
                ul.animate({
                    'left': ui.value * -1
                }, 500);
            },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
                console.log(ui.value);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

link to my issue: http://www.floodgateone.com/catering/index1.html

thanks for any help

Comment: Why page load instead of document ready?

Comment: And what's with that `charset` attribute?

Comment: which part of it is not working? try wrap all of them inside $(document).ready(function(){//code here});

Comment: The `slider` method is from a plug-in, right? In that case, it could be that that plug-in is not compatible with 1.6.2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're upgrading jQuery, then also upgrade to the latest [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) where slider setup is much easier:

```
$(".slider").slider();
```

**EDIT:**

Working example, using latest jQuery and jQuery UI: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wD9D/1/)

Full-screen link: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4wD9D/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: did you see the link to the example page? link to my issue: http://www.floodgateone.com/catering/index1.html

Comment: Yes, and it looks like you need to also upgrade to the latest ui.slider plugin (and dimensions and ui.mouse) http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: Posted working fiddle link. Same content but with latest jQuery and jQuery UI. http://jsfiddle.net/4wD9D/1/

Comment: is there any way that i could add next and previous to make this move left and right by 450px at any one time? thanks for all your help so far you've been a great help.

Comment: Working fine for me though you don't need <div class="handle"></div>... perhaps that's getting in your slider's way? (read through the slider docs/demos to modify the handle) http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: seems to be ok now how do i add the animate back in on click to stop function

Comment: @Paul let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1603/discussion-between-macroj-and-paul)

Comment: one more thing the slider handle goes off each end of the slider and disappears is there any way of stopping this? and is there a way of adding arrows that move it left and right?